# Codeigniter - how to reuse code to generate a block of HTML

Tags: php, codeigniter

I think I might be approaching this in the wrong way, so I would appreciate any comments/guidance. Hopefully I can explain coherently enough what I am trying to achieve:

- I want to create a block of HTML
  (e.g. a box containing a user's
  profile), which I will load as part
  of my layout on most pages that I
  generate.
- I would also like to be able to
  re-generate the content within this
  box on its own from a separate URL. This is so I can update the box with an AJAX call.
- I don't want to duplicate the code
  that creates this HTML.

I appreciate that I could initally load this box using an AJAX call, but that would seem to me to add an unnecessary call to the server?

The way I thought I could do it is by having a method in my controller that just renders this block of HTML, but how would I then request the output from this method within another controller / view?

How would you approach this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a view to generate the block of HTML for the user's profile and call it from your controller using:

```
$user_html = $this->load->view('user_view', $user_data, true);
```

The third parameter returns the view as a string instead of displaying it. This can then be passed into another view in the usual way.

```
$data['user_block'] = $user_html;
$this->load->view('page_view', $data);
```

Comment: However, this won't give you a seperate URL that you can use for an AJAX call.

Comment: THanks. So I suppose the key thing here is to put all the processing of the data inside the model so I have as little code in the controller as possible.

Comment: I guess though if the bulk of code is in models and views, then controller isn't actually doing a lot, so it would be only a few lines of duplicated stuff

Comment: Copying and pasting the same code across all your controllers kinda ruins the point of using frameworks and OOP. However I should stfu as I don't have a better answer. Still thinking of a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: The only code that would be duplicated across controllers would be about three lines to get the data from the model, pass it into the user_view and then send the returned html into the main view for the page.

Comment: As tomhaigh pointed out - all of the code that actually generates the HTML (the code you really don't want to be duplicated) is not duplicated.

Answer (score -1):

As far as data is concerned, you dont 'need' to generate the HTML with PHP. You can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to generate the necessary elements from a JSON object output in the page source. You can then show a nice little 'loading' animation on the element whilst it gets around to hitting a state of 'domready'.

As far as repopulating a div is concerned, do the following:

Make a div for your profile and give it an id.
Put each 'element' of data into it's own p element and wrap the actual data in a span element. 
e.g 
<p>Name: <span>Joe Bloggs</span></p>
Then simply use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to traverse the dom and repopulate the spans with data. Just make sure you output your data in the correct 'order'.

Any questions, feel free to feedback.

Comment: I see your point, but I would rather use javascript to progressively enhance a site rather than relying on it for things I should really be able to do server-side

Comment: Please give an example of the sort of html you would like to be generated dynamically.